# Why atomic operation only works within a thread group in HLSL compute shader?

Tags: parallel-processing, hlsl, compute-shader

I have two buffers, `src` and `target`. `src` are random values with duplicates (maybe something like `{1,3,1,3,2,3,...}`). `target` is initially all-zero.

What I want to do is like (in c++ syntax):

```
for (int i : src) {
    target[i]++;
}
```

But I want to do it in HLSL compute shaders. Due to the duplicates in `src`, there may be data races. So I implemented `AtomicAdd` operation:

```
#define AtomicAdd(BUFFER, IDX, VALUE) \
keepWaiting = true;\
do {\
    uint ov;\
    InterlockedCompareExchange(BUFFER##_Mutex[IDX], 0, 1, ov);\
    if (ov == 0) {\
        BUFFER[IDX] += VALUE;\
        BUFFER##_Mutex[IDX] = 0;\
        keepWaiting = false;\
    }\
} while (keepWaiting)
```

In the compute shader with only one group like:

```
// called by group number (1, 1, 1)
[numthreads(512, 1, 1)]
void kernel(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID) {
    for (uint i = 0; i <= SrcSize / 512; i++) {
        uint idx = i * 512 + id.x;
        if (idx >= SrcSize) {
            return;
        }

        bool keepWaiting;

        uint srcValue = src[idx];

        AtomicAdd(Target, srcValue, 1);
    }
}
```

It works well (at least on my device). But In the compute shader with many groups like:

```
// called by group numbers (X, 1, 1), X is a large number and X * 512 > SrcSize.
[numthreads(512, 1, 1)]
void kernel(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID) {
    if (id.x >= SrcSize) {
        return;
    }

    bool keepWaiting;

    uint srcValue = src[idx];

    AtomicAdd(Target, srcValue, 1);
}
```

It does not produce correct results.

So my question is: why this happens? What is the difference between these two kernels?